# Fixing POSIX sh warning in a small Bash program

Tags: bash, sh

I wrote the following code in Bash:

```
#!/bin/sh

host=$1
regex="^(((git|ssh|http(s)?)|(git@[\w\.]+))(:(\/\/)?)([A-Za-z0-9.@:_/-]+)\.com)(.*)"
if [[ "$host" =~ $regex  ]]; then
    d=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    if [[ "$d" = *github* ]]; then
        return
    fi
fi
die "Current repository is not stored in Github."
```

I want to learn how to write a better Bash code so I use the shellcheck.net.

```
Line 5:
if [[ "$host" =~ $regex  ]]; then
   ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, [[ ]] is undefined.

Line 6:
    d=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, array references are undefined.

Line 7:
    if [[ "$d" = *github* ]]; then
       ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, [[ ]] is undefined.
```

I'm trying to understand how to fix those warnings. I understand that in order to fix `[[ ]]` I need it to switch to `[ ]` but then I get an error due globs. Also how should I replace the `=~` operator?

Comment: I don't understand. There is no fixing, you have to remove it. `[[` is not posix.

Comment: Do you mean to write a script for Bash, as you say, or for the POSIX shell?  The former can emulate the latter, but Bash has more features (and you are using some of its extensions).

Comment: If you want shellcheck to check your script as bash then you need to put `bash` at the top, not `sh`, or select it explicitly in shellcheck.

Comment: @vesii : You should make up your mind: Do you want to write a POSIX shell script (in which case it's maybe better to use _dash_  or _ash_ instead of bash)? In this case you have to write it from scratch using POSIX constructs, which means no `[[`,  hence no regex, nor any of the other goodies bash has to offer. Or do you want to write  a bash script? Then your `[[`  is fine; no point in changing it.

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between `sh` and `bash`. They are two different languages with different specifications. While it is true that `bash` understands `sh` syntax, it is not true that `sh` understands all `bash` syntax. The errors that pop up are all referencing bash features , not part of  `sh`. A useful webpage might be  [this Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.28.28), but it does not tell you everything. The [posix standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18) might help you out further in combinatin with `man test`.

Answer (score 6):

When you write `#!/bin/sh` then you shouldn't use bash-specific features like `[[`. But you don't need to change `[[` to `[` or anything like that; just change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash`. Then you can use all the bash features you like.

Comment: Right.  But it remains unclear whether for the OP, "how to write a better Bash code" includes writing code that conforms to the POSIX shell language.

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep` and `sed` in posix.

```
# use grep -q to match with regex
if printf "%s\n" "$host" | grep -q '\(git\|ssh\|http\(s\)\)etc. etc. etc.'; then
    # use sed to extract part of the string matching regex
    d=$(printf "%s\n" "$host" | sed 's/\(g\|ssh\|http\(s\)\)etc. etc. etc./\2/')
    if printf "%s\n" "$d" | grep -q github; then
       return
    fi
fi
```

Finding out proper regexes is left to others.

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted, it answers the OP's question quite well as it seems they want to understand how to replace these Bash constructs, rather than just yield to using Bash.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to parse out the different parts with [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) though it's going to get a bit tedious. (The link is to the Bash manual; only a few of the expansions supported by Bash are POSIX.)

Assuming the input is a valid, well-formed URL (which may or may not be warranted) maybe try

```sh
host=$1
tail=${1#*://*/}
case $tail in "$host") tail=${host#*/};; esac
case ${host%/$tail} in
   *github.com) return ;;
esac
die "Current repository is not stored in Github."
```

(where of course we assume that this is in a context where `return` makes sense, and where `die` is defined separately, like we have to assume in the original code).

This is quite a lot simpler than the regex you presented, and definitely does not cover all the strings that the regex would be able to handle; but perhaps it doesn't have to be all that complex if we can assume that the URL has gone through some sort of validation (i.e. if it's the output from `git remote` it's pretty safe to assume that the user has verified it by other means already).